# Using Selenium webdriver with a custom firefox profile - how to get rid of addins popup

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

When I use selenium webdriver with a custom firefox profile I get the firefox Add-ons pop up showing 2 extensions: Firefx WebDriver 2.5.0 and Ubuntu Firefox Modifications 0.9rc2.

How can I get rid of this popup? I looked in the server jar to see if I could find the extensions, no luck. Looked online for the extensions, no luck. When I run the code without using the custom profile there is no popup.

Comment: Not really sure which popup you mean, what does it say? A screenshot would also be ok. Is that Firefox 3.6 saying that new add-ons have been installed? Because I cannot think of anything matching your description in newer Firefox versions.

Comment: Yes it is the new add-ons have been installed popup, Adam's solution worked. Thank you - Jamie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an entry called extensions.newAddons to the profile's preferences and set the value to false.

Start firefox with the custom profile

```
firefox -profile <path to profile directory>
```

Type **about:config** in the address bar and press the *enter* key. Right-click the preference pane to open the context menu and go to **New -> Boolean**.
Enter **extensions.newAddons** for the preference name. Select **false** for the new boolean value.

The entry should prevent the new addon window from appearing when you start Firefox with that profile.

Answer (score 0):

Open Firefox with this profile (with profile manager), go to Firefox preferences, turn off updates - this works for me.